# My js function cant handle with 2 calling in the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im call this function in the same time.

**first call:** run in `setInterval` and jump without my animation,

**second call:** run after `$(document).ready` and do it right.

```
fadeInFadeOut : function (oldContent, newContent, flag) {
                    hcGlobal.animateFlag = flag
                    switch (hcGlobal.animateFlag) {
                      case true: 
                        $( oldContent ).stop().animate({
                                'top' : '30px',
                                'opacity' : '0'
                            }, 400, 'easeInOutBack', function() {
                                $( this ).html( newContent );
                                if (hcGlobal.animateFlag) {
                                    $( this ).animate({
                                       'top' : '0px',
                                       'opacity' : '1'
                                    }, 400, 'easeInOutBack');

                                    hcGlobal.animateFlag = false          
                                 }
                        });
                        break;

                    case false:       
                        $( oldContent ).html( newContent );
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Why its happing? there is a way to handle with multiple calling in the same time on one function?

Thanks.

Comment: What is issue? Does first `setInterval` call, before `.ready()` not return expected result?

Comment: its work but without ease. its change my content without animation.

Comment: Is `jQuery UI` defined, or jQuery easings plugin included?

Comment: jQuery UI only.

Comment: i add setInterval for my second call and its work fine. but i think its don't the correct way.

Comment: Make `setInterval` call within `.ready()` handler, after elements are loaded into `document`

Comment: Second animate needs a stop too: $( this ).animate({ => $(this).stop().animate({

Comment: Its dont work for me

Comment: Add a complete working example that "don't work for you"...

Comment: They never run at the same time, javascript is singlethreaded. I rather think that your problem might be that you are using a global property and that your animate callback has no longer the reference to the original flag you put in the `hcGlobal.animateFlag`. there you could use binding or parametrizing the callback of the animate callback to make sure you are going to the old reference, and not the new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used two function inside another function(example). you can also see, i have used setInterval and ready() functions and executing simultaneously.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
<body onload="myMove()">

<div id ="container">
<div id ="animate">
<p>hello</p>
</div>
</div>

<script>
function myMove() {

   setInterval(function(){

  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos+

    +; 
          elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
          elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
        }
      }
    },3000);

    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("p").text("hi");
    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```